# display style for table row to stay aligned with header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and using javascript I give the user the option to remove table rows from the table by putting the display style to none.
If the user wants to see the rows again, I need to put the display style away from none and my problem is that I don't know what style to use. I thought table-row-group is the most sensible, but it messes up the rows...
I created a fiddle here and copied the code below

https://jsfiddle.net/b2s3dpo5/#&togetherjs=7EwfsBJIfw

```
<fieldset style="display: inline-block;">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ category.name }}" id="category" checked> remove rows&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="panel panel-default col-xs-12">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
    <th><strong>test test test</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Institute/Organisation</strong></th>
    <th><strong>test deadline test</strong></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="category">
    <th class="col-xs-1" scope="row">
      test
    </th>
    <td class="col-xs-5">
      test
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-4">
      test
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-2">
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and the necessary javascript

```
document.getElementById('category').onclick = function() {
  toggleSub_by_class(this, 'category');
};

function toggleSub_by_class(box, select_class) {
// get reference to related content to display/hide
 var el = document.getElementsByClassName(select_class);
 var flag;

 if (box.checked) {
   for (var i = 0, j = el.length; i < j; i++) {
     el[i].style.display = 'table-row-group';
   }
 } else {
   for (var i = 0, j = el.length; i < j; i++) {
     var classList = el[i].className.split(' ')
     flag = 0
     for (var h = 0, k = classList.length; h < k; h++) {
       if (document.getElementById(classList[h])) {
         if (document.getElementById(classList[h]).checked) {
           flag = 1
         }
       }
     }
     if (flag == 0) {
       el[i].style.display = 'none';
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: fiddle is not working (

Comment: sorry... it is working now

Comment: Rather than set the style, use a class with display: none; and add or remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try `visibility:hidden` or `height:0px` or both.

Comment: Then toggle it back to `visibility: visible;`... I would personally think leaving `height` untouched to be better than fooling with it... :D

Comment: @JefréN.-agreed that its better to do one thing rather than 2. But visibility:hidden will leave a blank space where the content was and this might or might not be the OP's intention.

Comment: Hi grateful... the visibility hidden function is great, but I do need to remove the entire row. setting the height to 0px does not seem to work... I added el[i].style.height = '0px'; to the code

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself... the correct display style is empty

```
el[i].style.display = '';
```

that works fine for me
carl

Comment: you can also use `'table-row'`.

Answer (score -1):

First off, for readability purposes, try to create more concise headers when you share it with the rest of the community (although I understand that this is not a big deal).

---

I would try

```
    visibility:hidden
```

Comment: yes that has been suggested before, I am just wondering how to get rid of the free space left when using this function...